# Install package to Ubuntu 16.04 installation while booted into live cd

Tags: live-usb

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto my hard disk.

After tingling with the nvidia drivers and installing xserver-xorg-core or something (I was trying to get bumblebee and optirun to work), I found a post saying `xserver-xorg-input-all` **was not installed** - which left me with a system that **I can boot into**, **but not interact with**.

I tried recovery mode, but my laptop only has wifi (or LAN via USB-Stick, which I think would probably be as complicated to get to work) and I cannot manage to get network up and working in recovery mode.

So I started a live cd / live-USB-Stick with Ubuntu 16.04 (that I used to install Ubuntu) and it mounted my hard drive with Ubuntu on it as well.

**Is there a way to somehow install that package into the installation of Ubuntu on my hard drive while running live Ubuntu?**

Comment: Short answer: NO.

Comment: might this possible with `chroot`?

Comment: @mjb2kmn I had a brief look into chroot and it **seems** as if it might be just the tool to do what I want (I found a tutorial explaining how to use chroot with /mnt in order to reset the root password using passwd). **If you could elaborate a bit on chroot and perhaps offer an example on what to do to install a package to an installation** (after having fired up a terminal from within a booted recovery-CD/-flashdrive), *I woulld greatly appreciate it and mark the answer as correct if it works*. Meanwhile I solved the problem by connecting via USB-LAN in recovery mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's difficult to speak to the exact situation with `xserver-xorg-input-all`, however, I can show how to install packages on an installation booted from a live image.

I tested this with a Xubuntu 17.04 VM.

#### Summary of steps

- Boot from a compatible live image, preferably the one you installed from.
- Mount the root volume of the installation.
- Bind mount `/dev`, `/proc`, and `/sys` inside the root volume mount.
- Bind mount `/run` if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. This is required on Ubuntu 17.04, but I'm not sure if it is on 16.04. This is required for DNS name resolution.
- `chroot` into the mounted file system.
- Install, uninstall, or configure as needed.
- Reboot into installation.

#### Actual commands

The device you're mounting in the first command will need to be adjusted to match your installation's root volume.

```
mount /dev/xubuntu-vg/root /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /run /mnt/run # if needed, as noted above
chroot /mnt
apt install gnucash # or whatever you need
```

#### Wrap up

I was able to install `gnucash`, an application I did not previously have installed and which has many dependencies. After a reboot, GnuCash was installed and functional.

Note that I did not update the cache with `apt-get update` before installing, this was intentional because I knew my cache on the installation was up-to date enough. Depending on your situation, updating the cache may be necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it on my laptop (where I installed Ubuntu 16.04) and it seemed to work just the way I wanted.

Comment: **Correction:** Under "Wrap up" in answer 1 above, it refers to `apt-cache update`, but I believe this should read `apt-get update`. Apologies if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the note, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Also: if the application I want to install is in a different repository (ppa), I have to add that repository and - at least it seemed so - use `apt-get update` in order to be able to install that application.