# kernel panic after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: kernel, 18.10

Well, crap. I felt brave and let 18.10 install over 18.04, and it apparently didn't go well.

I'm hitting a kernel panic at boot (error loading libargon2.so.0).

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu - is there a way to recover this - perhaps from a usb boot installation, without losing all of my current settings and applications?

Comment: you can use this link, may be it helps, you don't tell us what is really wrong so... https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078

Comment: Not sure what else I can tell you. Boot fails due to a kernel panic caused by the missing file.
But there are some good links there. I'll see if I can fix it from a live usb.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it. I tried different solutions so maybe some steps are redundant or missing:

1. Boot from Ubuntu Live USB (in my case it was 18.04 LTS).
2. Open Nautilus.
3. In left bottom side click on "Other locations"
4. Select your old Ubuntu drive and open it (you will be in the root folder of your old Ubuntu, in my case it was something like `/mnt/f3kljjhfu23oghggnmnjyy`)
5. Open terminal in this folder.
6. Make mirrors for folders:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev ./dev
   sudo mount --bind /sys ./sys
   sudo mount --bind /proc ./proc
   ```
7. After this command you will be like root for old Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo chroot .
   ```
8. Open a browser and download deb file of `libargon2-0` for your OS from [Debian packages repository](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libargon2-0) (in my case file was named like `libargon2-0_0~20171227-0.1_amd64.deb`).
9. Copy the downloaded file to *tmp* file of your old Ubuntu (`/mnt/f3kljjhfu23oghggnmnjyy/tmp`)
10. Install the downloaded deb file using the terminal from step #7 (so it will be installed to old Ubuntu):

    ```
    dpkg --install /tmp/libargon2-0_0~20171227-0.1_amd64.deb
    ```
11. After successful package installation restart your computer and boot to your old Ubuntu (you may want to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on Ubuntu's loading screen to watch the status of loading)

PS. You may like an instruction from this guy, which helped me a lot -
[Install package to Ubuntu 16.04 installation while booted into live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976894/install-package-to-ubuntu-16-04-installation-while-booted-into-live-cd)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you used BTRFS for your drives, you could restore to a snapshot from before the installation.  It would work best.