# Kernel panic after upgrade to 18.04, boot-repair via usbflash failed

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-repair

My boot directory seems to be full. I can't find a manual how to delete old kernels via usbflash. I don't know how to get to the hard drive boot folder when operating in usbflash. And I am afraid to delete sensible data of my old installation. But this shouldn't be the case if I only manipulate the boot folder, right. Btw it is also not possible to start from any of the other old installations listed in the grub. I did run boot-repair, but it failed and left me this report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VgT8XjnyKR/
The hints here --> 
[kernel panic after upgrade to 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085088/kernel-panic-after-upgrade-to-18-10)
sound good. But I am overasked to understand the boot-repair report and would be verz thankful for tips eighter on how to save my old data via usbflash or how to make the old installation running.

Kernel panic screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your boot directory is not full. It is stored in the Ubuntu root partition on /dev/sda4, which is 616 Gb and nearly half-empty (see line 1286). What is the exact kernel panic?

Comment: Thanks Jos! As i currently have no possibility to upload a screenshot of the panic elsewhere but in posting an answer here, forgive me to do that..., 1 sec

Comment: The usual procedure is to upload a screenshot (or an actual photo if a screenshot is not possible) to imgur.com. A friendly editor with some reputation will then paste it into your question.

Comment: ok, cool, here are two screenshots https://imgur.com/a/VaZxTJS

Comment: Browsing through various solutions for this phenomenon I came across this one: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=145252#p765027 . Please try it out (replacing `sda7` by `sda4` for your case). If it doesn't work, it is very probably harmless.

Comment: this is what happens: https://imgur.com/a/1NmeM5x unfortunately i don't know what this means :-/

Comment: That would point to a hardware error (which is frequently a source of kernel panic). Please back up sensitive data at this point. Then unmount `/dev/sda4` and run a `fsck -V /dev/sda4`.

Comment: now I am about to make a .img backup of that sda4, it takes another hour. Than I'll do the file system check. Thanks, Jos!

Comment: Mind you, your backup of the full partition may *also* suffer from an input/output error. Backup your home directory first.

Comment: check says the partition is alright: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -V /dev/sda4
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda4] fsck.ext4 /dev/sda4 
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda4: clean, 704573/40992768 files, 91475040/163959961 blocks

Comment: But can you boot now without a kernel panic?

Comment: No, i can't. Not in the latest installed kernel, not in the oldest recovery version. Here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/J0tAmOL But so far i didn't modify anything anyway, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: tried to repair the indicated firmware bug, but i get the contradictory result that the firmware would be up to date. https://imgur.com/a/KtNqaPI