# How can I use an Linux Live Session (usb) to uninstall a prgram on my main drive?

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

Problem: I attempted to install Japanese language input onto my Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Yoga C930 and it caused the Black Screen of Death after crashing Firefox and then freezing all my inputs (mouse/keyboard). The Black Screen of Death appeared upon a restart which had previously unfrozen the machine.

I have the Live USB that I installed Linux with and I know what program caused the issue. How can I (if it is possible) use my live session to fix my issue on the main hard drive?

Things that work:

- Dual booted Windows 10 is unaffected
- Recovery tools work
- BIOS is accessible

EDIT TO EXPLAIN DIFFERENCE BETWEEN MY QUESTION AND SUGGESTED DUPLICATE:

1. The related question can boot their system, I cannot
2. My question is on a different ubuntu release and it is not clear that the same procedures work
3. I don't understand the solution provided on the [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976894) and don't have enough reputation to add comments to further clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install package to Ubuntu 16.04 installation while booted into live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976894/install-package-to-ubuntu-16-04-installation-while-booted-into-live-cd)

Comment: The easiest way is to boot into recovery mode and drop to a root shell. To do this, please follow steps 1 - 6 in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501 . you will then be able to uninstall the package easily.

Comment: @raffa I tried that solution, but the root shell prompt looks different from my terminal and so I wasn't sure that it was doing the same things.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the name of the package you want to uninstall and the commands you used to install it. Also try accessing the recovery mode by following the instructions in the linked answer in my second comment above. Thank you