# Install glibc in another location

Tags: compiling, make, glibc, data-corruption

I messed up my install of Ubuntu on another computer. I decided to plug in the drive to another Ubuntu machine and make install it. I'm trying my best to not corrupt the other machine. Here's what I did so far.

- Downloaded and extracted the `glibc-2.31` package
- Configured it using `../configure --prefix=/media/info/dc361950-ba80-44de-bbae-1543c8f20be9/usr/ --disable-profile --enable-add-ons`
- Ran `make`

Now, it's showing the error:

```
In file included from ../include/pthread.h:1,
                 from ../sysdeps/nptl/thread_db.h:25,
                 from ../nptl/descr.h:32,
                 from ../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tls.h:130,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h:24,
                 from <stdin>:1:
../sysdeps/nptl/pthread.h:719:47: error: argument 1 of type ‘struct __jmp_buf_tag *’ declared as a pointer [-Werror=array-parameter=]
  719 | extern int __sigsetjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag *__env, int __savemask) __THROWNL;
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from ../include/setjmp.h:2,
                 from ../nptl/descr.h:24,
                 from ../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tls.h:130,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h:24,
                 from <stdin>:1:
../setjmp/setjmp.h:54:46: note: previously declared as an array ‘struct __jmp_buf_tag[1]’
   54 | extern int __sigsetjmp (struct __jmp_buf_tag __env[1], int __savemask) __THROWNL;
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: What is your end goal here? if it is just to fix a broken glibc install, then it might be simpler to install the appropriate Ubuntu libc6 binary package - either via a chroot or by using the apt.conf RootDir option

Comment: ... see for example [Install package to Ubuntu 16.04 installation while booted into live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976894/install-package-to-ubuntu-16-04-installation-while-booted-into-live-cd) and [How to re-insall libc6 after remove?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191350/how-to-re-insall-libc6-after-remove)

Comment: @steeldriver How would I do this? That is my end goal...